# Change variable after a specific amount of time python

Tags: python, multithreading, timer

I need to be able to switch the value of a Boolean after a specific amount of time whilst the rest of my code continues running as usual. What happens in the main part of the code is dependent on the value of the Bool.

Here's my attempt with goodguy's suggestion, but I still can't get it to work. 'playing' switches to True when I call the class, but doesn't switch back to False after 2 seconds so the tone only plays once. What am I doing wrong?

```
class TimedValue:

   def __init__(self):
        self._started_at = datetime.datetime.utcnow()

    def __call__(self):
        time_passed = datetime.datetime.utcnow() - self._started_at
        if time_passed.total_seconds() > 2:
            return False
        return True

playing = False
while True:
    trigger = randint(0,10) # random trigger that triggers sound
    if trigger == 0 and playing == False:
    #play a tone for 2 seconds whilst the random triggers continue running
    #after the tone is over and another trigger happens, the tone should play again
        thread.start_new_thread(play_tone, (200, 0.5, 2, fs, stream,))
        value = TimedValue()
        playing = value()

    time.sleep(0.1)
```

Comment: Can you include the code for your best attempt so far? It's much easier to understand the issue if there's a starting basis.

Comment: Is that ok? I don't really have a best attempt, nothing is working.

Answer (score 1):

Threading and multiprocessing sounds like an overkill for this case. Another possible way is to define something like callable class whose instance remembers time it was created at for measurements:

```
import datetime

class TimedValue:

    def __init__(self):
        self._started_at = datetime.datetime.utcnow()

    def __call__(self):
        time_passed = datetime.datetime.utcnow() - self._started_at
        if time_passed.total_seconds() > XX:
            return True
        return False

value = TimedValue()
```

and when use `value()` as a callable in other parts of code

Comment: how to I get the returned value from the class? Sorry I'm new to this... I tried printing TimedValue and this is what I got:    

<__main__.TimedValue instance at 0x1049e33b0>

Comment: Like he said. value = TimedValue() and then anytime you need the value, call value().

Comment: In fact, even the use of `__call__` is a bit overkill. A property would be slightly easier to grasp for a beginner IMHO (my_timed_value.value). +1 for showing how to answer the need rather than how to do multiprocessing (avoiding XY issue).

Comment: IMO choice between property and callable class is a matter of taste in this case, but both are nice to have in your Python's arsenal. Thanks for bringing this up.

Comment: @Jérôme I've edited my code as to my understanding of this suggestion but my Bool still doesn't switch back to False after two seconds. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @goodguy: agreed, it's a matter of taste. I can only speak from my own experience / learning slope.

Comment: @ElanaLS: you may [upvote](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/173400/319469)/[accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) this answer, then.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `ThreadPool` class from the module `multiprocessing`:

```
import time

myBool = False

def foo(b):
     time.sleep(30) #time in seconds
     return not b

from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

pool = ThreadPool(processes=1)
result = pool.apply_async(foo,[myBool])

b = result.get()
```